# Why is bundler not installing gems stored in get repo properly?

Tags: git, rubygems, bundler, rvm, bundle-install

Bundler version 1.0.0.beta.2

Rvm Info

```
system:
  uname:        "Linux dane-r1f-ubuntu 2.6.32-22-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 28 13:27:30 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux"
  shell:        "bash"
  version:      "4.1.5(1)-release"

rvm:
  type:         "rvm is a function"
  version:      "rvm 0.1.31 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]"

ruby:
  interpreter:  "ruby"
  version:      "1.9.2dev"
  date:         "2010-05-31"
  platform:     "i686-linux"
  patchlevel:   "2010-05-31 revision 28117"
  full_version: "ruby 1.9.2dev (2010-05-31 revision 28117) [i686-linux]"

homes:
  gem:          "/home/dane/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-preview3@mmm"
  ruby:         "/home/dane/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-preview3"

binaries:
  ruby:         "/home/dane/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-preview3/bin/ruby"
  irb:          "/home/dane/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-preview3/bin/irb"
  gem:          "/home/dane/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-preview3/bin/gem"
  rake:         "/home/dane/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-preview3@mmm/bin/rake"

environment:
  GEM_HOME:     "/home/dane/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-preview3@mmm"
  GEM_PATH:     "/home/dane/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-preview3@mmm:/home/dane/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-preview3@global"
  BUNDLE_PATH:  "/home/dane/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-preview3@mmm"
  MY_RUBY_HOME: "/home/dane/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-preview3"
  IRBRC:        "/home/dane/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-preview3/.irbrc"
  RUBYOPT:      ""
  gemset:       "mmm"
```

`bundle install` doesn't appear to install any gems that are sourced from git in my `Gemfile`. Even though bundler says that it downloaded and used the repo successfully, `gem list` doesn't agree. Any thoughts on what may be wrong with this setup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bundler installs your gems into its own `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-{version}/bundler/gems` directory. This is independent from the main gems dir, which is why `gem list` will not list them. `bundle list` however will.

Comment: According to [this post](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/04/12/some-of-the-problems-bundler-solves/) by Yehuda Katz: 

"In 0.9, we solved this problem by placing gems installed by bundler into BUNDLE_PATH, which defaults to ~/.bundle/#{RUBY_ENGINE}/#{RUBY_VERSION}. rvm, which does not install executables or gems into a path owned by root, helpfully sets BUNDLE_PATH to the same location as GEM_HOME. This means that when using rvm, gems installed via bundle install appear in gem list."

Comment: HI, where to set the BUNDLE_PATH ?