# When I run 'bundle update' and I have git references, where are those git repositories saved?

Tags: git, bundle, bundler

If a Gemfile has:

```
gem 'akephalos', :git => "git@github.com:Nerian/akephalos.git"
```

When I do:

```
$ bundle update
```

I noticed that it only downloads the last commits, has it takes a lot of less time that the first 'bundle'.

Where is the git repo saved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this post](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/04/12/some-of-the-problems-bundler-solves/) by Yehuda Katz:

> We checked out the git repositories into BUNDLE_PATH (again, defaulting to ~/.bundle/#{RUBY_ENGINE}/#{RUBY_VERSION} or $GEM_HOME with rvm) using the --bare option. This allows us to share git repositories like the rails repository, and then make local checkouts of specific revisions, branches or tags as specified by individual Gemfiles.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175511/why-is-bundler-not-installing-gems-stored-in-get-repo-properly/3176514#3176514) states that:

> Bundler installs your gems into its own ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-{version}/bundler/gems directory.

So that when you do a `bundle update`, bundler can simply do a `git pull`.